# Starting tasks sequentially, but asynchronous

Tags: asynchronous, async-await, task

I hope that there are someone that can help me with this. I need to read a large set of files, but don't want the UI to freeze meanwhile. My idea is to read one file. Let the user do some work with it, while the rest of the files are loaded. The problem is that although I use async and await, the method performs synchronous.

Below is some of the code:

```
// Make two tasks, and start the first task
Task task1 = Task.Run(() => controller.LoadExcelSheet(date, firstLasXFile));
Task task2 = new Task(() => controller.LoadExcelFiles(date, fileListLASEX));
// Do something

// Await that the first task ends until the next task starts
await task1.ContinueWith(secondTask => task2.Start());

// Do something else
await task2;

// Do some final stuff
```

Answer (score 0):

[You should never use the `Task` constructor](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2014/05/a-tour-of-task-part-1-constructors.html) and [almost never use `ContinueWith`](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/10/continuewith-is-dangerous-too.html).

If you need to compose two methods, the proper way to do that is with another method. In this case, it can be a local method:

```
Task task1 = Task.Run(() => controller.LoadExcelSheet(date, firstLasXFile));
Task task2 = LoadExcelFilesAfterTask();

... // Do something

// Await that the first task ends
await task1;

... // Do something else

await task2;

... // Do some final stuff

async Task LoadExcelFilesAfterTask()
{
  await task1;
  await Task.Run(() => controller.LoadExcelFiles(date, fileListLASEX));
}
```

Comment: Thank’s for the answer. I have realised that the problem may be due to that the methods I call is not supporting async/await. One of them is ExcelDataReader. Is there other free API for reading Excel files, supporting async/await?

Comment: @PärWästerby: I don't know of any library like that. While `async` support would be ideal, you can work around the lack of asynchronous support in a UI application by using `Task.Run`, as shown in my answer.